# Can't Compile using cuda in my program

Tags: qt, ubuntu, cuda

I have installed **CUDA-9.1** on **Ubuntu 16.4.4** and tried to compile a program which uses some libraries that need cuda. I succeeded when the installation was fresh but when I came back to it another day it failed and gave the following error.

> libnppc.so.9.1, needed by //usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libnppial.so.9.1, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

and can not find libnppc.so.9.1 which I found it in the same directory. 
I successfully compiled the program before and I did not change it at all but it fails.

I use Qt as my IDE and I added proper LIBS and INCLUDEPATH in .pro file.
I had the same problem using vscode as my IDE. I am sure that the problem is not related to my .pro file or the IDE or the program because it was working the other night.

Comment: Here is what I used in .pro file
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include /usr/local/zed/include /usr/local/cuda-9.1/include /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -L/usr/local/zed/lib -lsl_core -lsl_input -lsl_zed -L/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64 -lcudart -lcuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-lnppc should be added to end of the list